# C based hash table array returning incorrect value in search function

Tags: c, hashmap

I have an assignment for my algorithms course that involves the implementation of a chain-based hash table in C. I initialized an array of Linked List structs to simulate this behavior:

```
void * AllocateChainTable(int elementCountMax)
{
    Node ** array = calloc(elementCountMax, sizeof(Node *));
    for (int i = 0; i < elementCountMax; i++) {
        array[i] = initList();

    }
    return array;
}
```

Then, I implemented the assignment defined function InsertChain.

```
int InsertChain(    void * hashtable, int elementSize, int elementCountMax,
                            int key, void * element, int (*HashFunc)(int key))
{
    Node ** hashTable = hashtable;
    int hashedKey = HashFunc(key);
    insertAtHead(hashTable[hashedKey], element, key);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's insertAtHead. (I implemented my LLs with a dummy node.)

```
void insertAtHead(Node * node, void * data, int key) {
    int error = 0;
    Node * new = createNode(data, &error, key);
    if (error == 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (node->next == NULL) {
        node->next = new;
        int * size = (int *)node->data;
        *size++;
        return;
    }
    Node * oldHead = node->next->next;
    node->next = new;
    new->next = oldHead;
    int * size = (int *)node->data;
    *size++;
}
```

However, by the time I call my search function, the hash array returns a different object than what was expected viewing the insertion function.

```
void * SearchChain(void * hashtable, int key, int elementSize, int (*HashFunc)(int key))
{
    Node ** hashTable = hashtable;
    int hashKey = HashFunc(key);
    if (hashTable[hashKey]->next != NULL) {
        Node * startingNode = hashTable[hashKey]->next;
        while (startingNode != NULL) {
            if (startingNode->key == key) {
                return startingNode->data;
            }
            else {
                startingNode = startingNode->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I'm using a multiplication based hash function using Knuth's constant (sqrt(5)-1)/2). The keys are consistently being hashed correctly, but the returned values from `hashTable` are not matching up.

Is there a mistake I'm making with the Node ** array?

Comment: `Node * oldHead = node->next->next;`? Wouldn't the "old" head (before the insertion of the new head) be `node->next`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've got a dummy node before the main head to store size (I'm not entirely convinced it's necessary at this point, but y'know.)

Comment: Yes, `node` is the dummy node. But is also `node->next` a dummy? That would give you *two* dummy nodes, and it makes the assignment `node->next = new` wrong. I suggest you draw out the list on paper, and draw an arrow to the "actual head". Check this drawing against your code.